# how can i get Allocation fee and storage fee before transaction submit

Tags: fee

like this, i send the token in the first time to others, and i set the baker Fee by a no change number as 0.00135, but after transaction, i search it in explorer , i found it need 0.06425 to pay Allocation fee, so i want to know how can i get the size of Allocation fee
before transction,because i must got it before transaction to make the transaction come true.

there is the transaction example in tzkt.io, thank you, i am glad to receive your answers soon
https://tzkt.io/onuoXZ34omJBUsFn8ypsA5wRSZvj385rHkU4JYf7KGmciQfqA3v

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the estimate API in taquito: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/estimate